# Cobertura Line Coverage strange result

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura

Here's a sample of code from my project where Cobertura does not report a 100% line coverage :

```
if ( value == null) {
  return 0;
}
return 1;
```

The Cobertura report says that the 'return 1' line is never used. 
The problem is that if I print something right before the last return, I can see it in the output.
Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: @DavidWallace No. I misread the if branch, thought it also had a case of return inside.